# How to first create parent and then the child in a nested attribute creation form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2.12 webapp. In this app I got an account that has many users (through employees). I am creating the account and the user (employee) on the same time using nested attributes.

How can I first create the account and then the user (not at the same time).
I need to do this because I need to set account_id in the user model upon creation (cannot do it later since it is protected by Act as Tenant gem).

Thankful for all help!